# multiple windows, single tray icon

Tags: c, windows, winapi, system-tray, trayicon

My goal is to have a single icon for all the windows of my application.

After some reading, my understanding is that creating a tray icon is achieved through `Shell_NotifyIcon()`. This function gets a `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure which contains a `hWnd` field. This `HWND` is used by the system to notify the corresponding window of tray icon events. These events are handled by a `WindowProc` callback that is set on the window with `SetWindowLongPtr()`.

Hence my questions:

- How can a single icon notify all the windows of my app of say a left mouse click ?
- Can I `Shell_NotifyIcon()` multiple times with different `NOTIFYICONDATA` structures, each one with a different `hWnd`, but with the same icon ?
- What if the original window that got registered for creating the tray icon is destroyed ?

Would creating a hidden proxy window be an appropriate solution ?

Some background: my application calls the WinAPI with C (using js-ctypes), and should ideally work on all Windows versions from XP on.

Comment: A hidden window just for the notifications is the way to go, here's some code I wrote a long time ago which does this and may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341/A-Task-Tray-Applet-Framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You practically answered your own question in the question itself.  The best thing to do is create a hidden window that survives as long as you need the tray icon to exist.

You would call `Shell_NotifyIcon()` only once with the `hWnd` referring to this hidden window, and have this window post the messages to the individual windows that need to receive them.

This also gives you the flexibility of being able to decide to skip sending messages to a particular window, or being able to send a different message to each window, depending on the requirements of your particular application.